# How to combine :hover and :not in css

Tags: css

I understand that I can change another element's style when hovering on a different element like this:

```
.element-one:hover .element-two {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

But how can I change the style of all the elements in the page except element-two when I hover on element-one?

Comment: You can't unless all the other elements are siblings or children of `element-one`. You need javascript.

Comment: how would that looks like if they are siblings?

Comment: @Arash did you check my answer?

Comment: @Dekel, just noticed the edits

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.element-one:hover :not(.element-two)`.

Here is an example:

```css
.element-one:hover :not(.element-two) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.element-one {
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.element-one div {
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-one">
  <div class="element-two">
    element-two
  </div>

  <div class="element-three">
    element-three
  </div>

  <div class="element-four">
    element-four
  </div>
</div>
```

> However - note that it will work only for elements **inside** `element-one` and not for all the elements in the page.
>   You can do this with `body` for example, but the problem there is that `.element-two` is probably also inside some other element that exists inside `body`, and in such case the `.element-two` will get the opacity from it's containing element.

Comment: The problem with this is that no matter where the cursor is the style change is triggered. If I could do this for siblings (i.e. hover on two would make three and four change) then I could probably work with it. Is that possible with css?

Comment: Yes, you can use the sibling selector `~`